# PHP replace echo in str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I would like to use a php function for a string. Here's an example:

```
$txt = '123';
echo $fin = str_replace('2',"<?php echo 8; ?>",$txt);
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
183
```

But this is what I get:

```
13
```

Comment: why do you add a php tag inside your string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tr this

```
$txt = '123';
$fin = str_replace('2','8',$txt);
echo $fin;
```

Comment: No no, I want return php function into string. i want string get php tags

Comment: why do u need to do so.?

Comment: I want replace php codes in string and run in htm, example : str_replace('2','if(z==1)',$txt); . and after run this code if(z==1) is work. like weblog template !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `<?php echo 8; ?>`

juste do `echo $fin = str_replace('2','8',$txt);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable instead of a string if thats what you need:

```
$txt = '123';
$search = '2';
$replace = '8';
$end = str_replace($search,$replace,$txt);
echo $end;
```

This way you can use a function to change the search and change string if needed.